# Ruby: To make a string cache, which is faster: Array or SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby, arrays, caching

I'm making a ruby server with a cache of info about the online clients. This info should be preserved when I turn off the server. I can store it in a simple array and save it with Marshal or I can use a SQL database (MySQL, probably). Which is better to use? I think the Array method is easly, but the SQL is faster than? Thanks!

Comment: In memory is always easy and fast, but scalability should be considered if you think your server will become popular. Keeping lots of data in RAM can be a real pain when you have to wait for the server to load it into memory after a crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I would expect storing the serialized array to be significantly faster, as no indexing or additional row allocation needs to take place. I think it all depends on whether you want to be able to perform queries on the information. If not, you don't really need a database, you just need persistence. You might as well write the cache to a file then.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on scalability requirements.  If you expect thousands of records, you should use SQL or another DB, although this imposes developer overhead.  If you're dealing with a small number, however, you could get by with just serializing objects and saving them to disk.